# Process Page Tables

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86, kernel

I'm interested in gaining a greater understanding of the virtual memory and page mechanism, specifically for Windows x86 systems. From what I have gathered from various online resources (including other questions posted on SO),

1) The individual page tables for each process are located within the kernel address space of that same process.

2) There is only a single page table per process, containing the mapping of virtual pages onto physical pages (or frames).

3) The physical address corresponding to a given virtual address is calculated by the memory management unit (MMU) essentially by using the first 20 bits of the provided virtual address as the index of the page table, using that index to retrieve the beginning address of the physical frame and then applying some offset to that address according to the remaining 12 bits of the virtual address.

Are these three statements correct? Or am I misinterpreting the information?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, first lets clarify some things:

1. In the case of the x86 architecture, it is not the operating system that determines the paging policy, it is the CPU (more specifically it's MMU). How the operating system views the paging system is independent of the the way it is implemented. As a commenter rightly pointed out, there is an OS specific component to paging models. This is subordinate to the hardware's way of doing things.
2. 32 bit and 64 bit x86 processors have different paging schemes so you can't really talk about the x86 paging model without also specifying the word size of the processor.

What follows is a massively condensed version of the 32 bit x86 paging model, using the simplest version of it. There are many additional tweaks that are possible and I know that various OS's make use of them. I'm not going into those because I'm not really familiar with the internals of most OS's and because you really shouldn't go into that until you have a grasp on the simpler stuff. If you want the to know all of the wonderful quirks of the x86 paging model, you can go to the Intel docs: [Intel System Programming Guide](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/325384.pdf)

In the simplest paging model, the memory space is divided into 4KB blocks called pages. A contiguous chunk of 1024 of these is mapped to a page table (which is also 4KB in size). For a further level of indirection, All 1024 page tables are mapped to a 4KB page directory and the base of this directory sits in a special register `%cr3` in the processor. This two level structure is in place because most memory spaces in the OS are *sparse* which means that most of it is unused. You don't want to keep a bunch of page tables around for memory that isn't touched.

When you get a memory address, the most significant 10 bits index into the page directory, which gives you the base of the page table. The next 10 bits index into that page table to give you the base of the physical page (also called the physical frame). Finally, the last 12 bits index into the frame. The MMU does all of this for you, assuming you've set `%cr3` to the correct value.

64 bit systems have a *4 level* paging system because their memory spaces are much more sparse. Also, it is possible to page sizes that are not 4KB.

To actually get to your questions:

1. All of this paging information (tables, directories etc) sits in kernel memory. Note that kernel memory is one big chuck and there is no concept of having kernel memory for a single process.
2. There is only one page *directory* per process. This is because the page directory defines a memory space and each process has exactly one memory space.
3. The last paragraph above gives you the way an address is chopped up.

Edit: Clean up and minor modifications.

Comment: The paging scheme is not OS independent as you are saying. Linux, for example, handles paging in a different way compared to vanilla unix and it is not the 10:10:12 model.

Comment: Thanks very much for this insight. Virtual addresses are 32 bits, correct? Not 32 bytes as you stated in the third (last) paragraph. Or was that just a typo?

Comment: What I was trying to say was that the paging model used by the OS and the model used by the hardware are often distinct concepts. Linux uses a uniform paging model internally but this is layered on top of the hardware's paging model and requires architecture specific hacks to get it to work. It is the hardware's model that determines how address translation actually occurs (since it is the MMU that does this). Linux simply adds a layer of indirection on top. Deep in its bowels it still uses the 10:10:12 model.

Comment: Unfortunately the link you provided is not functional. Although with a little effort I think I have located the correct systems information library here: http://developer.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm

Comment: Note that huge pages are available on 32 bit x86 too: in the case of a huge page, the page directory entry points directly to the page frame.  This means that the last 22 bits of the virtual address are an offset within the page frame - x86 huge pages are thus 4M in size.

Comment: @AbhayBuch So suppose there are 1024 processes running in the OS. So all page tables(1024 for each process) of all processes will be stored in kernel memory? I think it will require 1024 * 1024 * 4KB = 4 GB space, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Overall that's pretty much correct.

If memory serves, a few details are a bit off though:

1. The paging for the kernel memory doesn't change per-process, so all the page tables are always visible to the kernel.
2. In theory, there's also a segment-based translation step. Most practical systems (e.g., *BSD, Linux, Windows, OS/X), however, use segments with their base set to 0 and limit set to the address space limit, so this step ends up as essentially a NOP.

Comment: In response to your first point: do you mean to say that the kernel address space per process always contains the same information; therefore, all of the page-tables for each process are stored in every virtual address space (but the kernel address space for each process maps on to the same physical frames)?

Comment: @Jimmy: No, the page tables aren't necessarily in every virtual address space. They will *all* be directly visible to the kernel though. To switch to a particular address space, the page tables for that address space have to be visible to the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; although I don't see how this invalidates any of my original three statements. I just didn't mention the fact that each individual address space was visible to the kernel.

Comment: Segment limits were (are?) used on OpenWall Linux to provide non-executable stacks (the exception that proves the rule, if you will).