# Worker process that acts like a worker thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, c11, setlocale

I have a multithreaded application which makes use of a library that basically reads files from disk and streams the data to a buffer for another subsystem to consume.

Now normally I would have done this with either:

- a single-threaded asynchronous model;
- a worker thread.

There is a constraint however: the library expects the default `"C"` locale to be in effect, whereas the rest of the application works with the current environment locale.

Thus I thought of maybe isolating it in a *worker process* instead by:

1. setting up the locale
2. fork'ing very early from the main thread
3. rolling the locale settings back to default in the child
4. stopping the worker process from the parent (with `SIGSTOP`)
5. waking it up as jobs drop by (via `SIGCONT`)

Something along the lines of:

```
int main(...) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // apply current locale

    // mmap shared memory, allocate synchronization primitives..

    pid_t worker = fork();
    if (worker == 0) {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); // apply default C locale

        do_grunt_work(); // loop somehow, waiting for command from parent

        _Exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    // stop child execution

    // do parent stuff..

    // raise termination flag and resume child execution

    waitpid(worker, NULL, 0); // join
    return 0;
}
```

I don't have much experience in multi-process programming, this is all I came up with and right now it seems a bit convoluted to me. Hence :

**Is there a more suited approach / pattern to this problem?** Isn't forking for such *simple* tasks too heavy? Does forking early helps keeping the child lightweight?

Comment: "Too heavy" depends on amount of work your child has to do, but anyways fork will not copy entire memory from it's parent, it will copy a page table and use copy-on-write for further memory accesses. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724641/the-only-overhead-incurred-by-fork-is-page-table-duplication-and-process-id-crea). In this case I would create a shared memory segment and a named semaphore. Worker process would fill up this segment and post on semaphore once work is completed. On the other side parent could wait with a timeout using 'sem_timedwait` for worker output

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make these as separate programs from the start then use IPC between them? Sounds like a much cleaner solution than some fork mess with multiple locales.